# How to detect last extra Empty Line and Ignore it in C (using getc)

Tags: c

Hello I am using this code for reading floating numbers in txt. If end of txt file has extra blank empty line program reads it 0.00000 and this affect my calculation  [Last empty line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NooOA.png)

(# means end of the calculation I added comment line if it exist update comment line)

I try "getline" and other function I can't fix it

```
fptr = fopen(fileName,"r+"); 
    if(fptr == NULL){
        printf("Error!! Cannot open file: %s \n", fileName );
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("File opened successfully\n");
        while((c = getc(fptr)) != '#' && c != EOF) {    

            fscanf(fptr,"%f" ,&arr[i]);      
            ++i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't mix `fscanf` and `getc` in the same loop. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense anyway, can you try to explain it?

Comment: You need `ungetc`. E.g `ungetc(c, fptr); fscanf(fptr,"%f" ,&arr[i]);`

Comment: @Dai I used getc beacuse of I add txt file comment line start "#" and If I start to program again I don't want to read last comment line

Comment: You are mistaken: `fscanf()` *does not* read 0.0 from an empty trailing line.  Instead, it has a matching failure, and doesn't set anything value via the provided pointer.  If you see a zero at that position then it's because the zero was *already there*.

Comment: `fscanf()` doesn't read zeroes from *internal* blank lines either, for that matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the return value of `fscanf` -- it should return 1 when it successfully reads a number and 0 on that blank line.

Comment: "0 on that blank line." --> sure its is not `EOF` on that last _blank_ line?

Comment: how I can check return value I tried fscanf() but it is not working

Comment: @chux sometimes EOF on the last blank line

Comment: @YlmzCmlttn if (blank line with )EOF, `fscanf` does not return 0.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think EOF return -1 it is not problem but I can't check return value fscanf() can you help me ?

Comment: @YlmzCmlttn `ungetc(c, fptr); if(1 != fscanf(fptr, "%f" ,&arr[i])) break;`. Also You maybe need `double` type. (`%lf`, `double array[size];`)

Answer (score 1):

OP is reading a file, line by line and has 4 outcomes:

1. Successful translated to a number.
2. Line begins with a `#` or whitespace only.
3. No more input  (end-of-file).
4. Something else.

Suggest new approach: read line by line as text and then attempt various parsings.  It is important to check the return value of `*scanf()` to help determine success.

```
   printf("File opened successfully\n");
   float /* or double */ arr[N];
   size_t i = 0;
   char buffer[100];

   while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fptr)) {
     double x;
     char sof[2];
     if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf" ,&x) == 1) {
       if (i < N) {
         arr[i++] = x;
       } else {
         puts("No room");
       }
     } else if (sscanf(buffer, "%1s" , sof) != 1 || sof[0] == '#') {
       ; // quietly ignore white-space only lines and that begin with # 
     } else {
       puts("Unexpected input");
     }
   }
   fclose(fptr);
   puts("Done");
```